# Java jasper report NullPointerException

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new to Java and I am running into this issue that I can't figure out. I inherited this project and I have the following code in one of my scriptlets:

```
DefaultLogger.logMessage("DEBUG path: "+ reportFile.getPath());
DefaultLogger.logMessage("DEBUG parameters: "+ parameters);
DefaultLogger.logMessage("DEBUG jr: "+ jr);
bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, jr);
```

And I am getting the following results (the fourth line there is line 287 in FootwearReportsServlet.doGet):

```
DEBUG path: C:\Development\JavaWorkspaces\Workspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\RSLDevelopmentStandard\reports\templates\footwear\RslFootwearReport.jasper
DEBUG parameters: {class_list_subreport=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@b07af1, signature_path=images/logo_reports.jpg, submission_id=20070213154168780, test_results_subreport=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@5795ce, logo_path=images/logos_3.gif, report_connection_secondary=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2c39d2, testing_packages_subreport=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@1883d5f, signature_path2=images/logo_reports.jpg, tpid_subreport=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@17531fd, first_page_subreport=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport@12504e0}
DEBUG jr: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource@1630eb6
Apr 29, 2010 4:15:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet FootwearReportsServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:601)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:517)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:385)
    at com.rsl.reports.FootwearReportsServlet.doGet(FootwearReportsServlet.java:287)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What I can't figure out is where the null reference is. From the debug lines I can see that each parameter has a value. Could it be referring to a bad path to one of the images? Any ideas? For some reason my server won't start in debug mode in Eclipse so I am having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: Which JasperReports version is that?  Looking at exact source code file for that version is very helpful.

Comment: most likely it's this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/jasperreports/jasperreports/3.1.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRFiller.java

Comment: Could you post how you are creating the Datasource "jr"?

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the line where you are getting the error:

```
jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:89)
```

In the JRFiller source code it corresponds to

```
jasperPrint = filler.fill(parameters, dataSource);
```

The only thing that can cause a `NullPointerException` in this line is the case when `filler` is `null`. The parameters are not checked for `null` at this point.

Looking at the code of `createFiller` (line 134), you can easily see the condition in which that function returns a null pointer. So I guess you somehow forgot to specify the print order (`PRINT_ORDER_HORIZONTAL` or `PRINT_ORDER_VERTICAL`).

Comment: Excellent!  I'm looking through the API/documentation to try to find a way to set the print order...

Comment: The reasons of the answer is correct, but I just upgraded Jasper version and the problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem.

Roland Illig is right, the print order is missing. This might be because the compiled report file is missing required fields.

Adding a value to the print order field afterwards does not help, it just keeps crashing at the next position where another field is missing.

Use the same version of the compiler (for example iReport) and your runtime library.

Comment: I have had the same issue. Just noticed I have used different version to compile and run. Making them same solved my problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Remove order from all your series and categories.
It will remove this exception.